# Azure Advisor Recommendations using PowerShell

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

Get-AzAdvisorRecommendation -Category Cost  | Where-Object {$_.ImpactedField -eq "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"}

**I'm trying to get the Cost Property for Virtual MAchines on "Shut down or resize your virtual machine" but not able to get it similar with the Data shows in portal**

Automate the advisor recommendations using PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

The command seems right. I don't have this Azure advice myself, but I can look for

```
Get-AzAdvisorRecommendation -Category Cost | 
Where-Object {$_.ImpactedField -eq "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses"}
```

and it gives me the corresponding advice. This should also work with `"Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"`.

Are you sure the error *is displayed* when you omit the pipe?

Comment: I'm getting the below Output  but not same as the output from Azure Portal as Recommendations etc.

Comment: ResourceId           : /subscriptions/******/resourceGroups/RG/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/VM/providers/
                       Microsoft.Advisor/recommendations/11e94d61-4c29-9457-**-***
Category             : Cost
ExtendedProperties   : {[MaxCpuP95, 7], [MaxTotalNetworkP95, 0], [MaxMemoryP95, 23], [deploymentId, 5b246c7b-a412-468e-9af4-51d71c4c05b5]...}
Impact               : High
ImpactedField        : Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines
ImpactedValue        : VMNAME

Comment: LastUpdated          : 11/4/2020 7:35:30 AM
Metadata             : {}
RecommendationTypeId : e10b1381-5f0a-47ff-8c7b-37bd13d7c974
Risk                 : 
ShortDescription     : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Advisor.Cmdlets.Models.PsRecommendationBaseShortDescription
SuppressionIds       : {}
Name                 : 11e94d61-4c29-9457-***-***
Type                 : Microsoft.Advisor/recommendations

Comment: If the output of `Get-AzAdvisorRecommendation (-Category Cost)` isn't identical to those from Azure Portal Recommendations, I'd think PowerShell is connected to a wrong azure subscription. Is that possible? Output of `Get-AzureSubscription` as expected?

Comment: We can see these Vaules from Advisor Portal
<<< Virtual machine. Recommended actions. Potential savings*. Subscription. Recommendationrule. Last updated.  Action >>>

How to the get same from PowerShell

Answer (score 0):

Get-AzAdvisorRecommendation -Category Cost | Where-Object {$_.ImpactedField -eq "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty *ExtendedProperties*

I got the required answer with the query..

Thanks Casper!