# Unable to get Cost details for right-sizing Azure VMs using get-azadvisoreecommendations Powershell cmdlet

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm trying to build a custom report showing the cost savings figures from Azure Cost Advisor, using the get-azadvisorrecommendation cmdlet. I can get the VM reservation savings amount, but for right-sizing advice it doesn't give me the savings amounts, however these show in the portal.
There is an extendedproperties value, but this only gives:

```
---                -----
MaxCpuP95          9
MaxTotalNetworkP95 0
MaxMemoryP95       38
deploymentId       02538ce8-c03d-4fa9-b2bc-136096896b64
roleName           GW-BRS-2ivi
currentSku         Standard_F4s
targetSku          Standard_B4ms
```

How can I get the Savings amount values?

Answer (score 0):

We have tested our local environment, our local environment has the azure advisor recommendations for cosmos db.

Based on the azure advisor  recommendations we have used the below PowerShell cmdlet to pull the saving cost using the `get-azureadvisorrecommendations` cmdlet

```
Get-AzAdvisorRecommendation -Category Cost | Where-Object {$_.ImpactedField -eq "microsoft.documentdb/databaseaccounts"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ExtendedProperties
```

Here is the sample output for reference :

[image]

Alternatively, You can use [use MSGraph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/advisor/advisor-azure-resource-graph)  to accomplish this.

[Azure Advisor API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/advisor/)  contains  **Reccomendations**  Operation Category which will give you ability to programmatically get Azure Advisor Recommendations.

There is also an official  [Microsoft.Graph](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.Graph/1.3.0)  module available on the PowerShell Gallery.

Here is the reference output pulling the savings cost using the resource graph explorer from portal.

[image]

Here is the reference [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64682981/azure-advisor-recommendations-using-powershell) Thread.

Note : If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Comment: Hi, thanks the response. However the above query does not give savings amounts for Right Sizing Virtual Machines in either Powershell or using the Resource Graph explorer.